# json_encode with php as parameter to javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

i need a help to json_encode

i have a html

```
<a class="list_size" onclick="generate_size(<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($ukuran));?>);return false;" title="<?php echo $warna[$w]['warna']; ?>"><?php echo $warna[$w]['warna']; ?></a>
```

and this is the json of php variable of $ukuran

```
echo json_encode($ukuran);
output : [{"uk":"26"},{"uk":"27"},{"uk":"28"},{"uk":"29"},{"uk":"30"},{"uk":"31"},{"uk":"32"},{"uk":"33"},{"uk":"34"},{"uk":"35"}]
```

and this is the function of javascript

```
function generate_size(ukuran) {

    alert(ukuran.length + ukuran.uk[0])
}
```

when i using `alert(ukuran.length)` that will shown alert with 10, and that is correct.. but when i using `alert(ukuran.length + ukuran.uk[0])` i fail tu call this function..

if i see the json_encode above, if i `alert(ukuran.uk[0])` that should be shown 26

how to solve this problem.. i try to found it at google but not found working solution,
can someone help me?? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that ukuran[0] is {"uk":"26"} and not simply 26.  Are you sure you aren't looking for ukuran[0].uk?

Answer (score 0):

Try casting your string to an int

```
alert(ukuran.length + parseInt(ukuran.uk[0]));
```